# Matplotlib graphic's line smoothing

Tags: matplotlib, graphics

[bullets' trajectory comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3sJ34.png)

I'm a new python user. I'm using this powerful code to do scientific research and data analysis.

I'm writing my thesis in physics, I'm trying to describe and analyze the external ballistics behind the bullet flight.

I'm using matplotlib to draw graphics representing the bullet's parabolic path and the related cross points; given that I'd like to know if there is a special code to smooth up the graphic lines drawn following the real experimental data avoiding to have a graphic made by a lot of linear segments.

Thanks a lot to all of you!

Francesco

Comment: Hi Francesco and welcome on stackoverflow. I find your question quite general and it would be useful if'd add an example of your script and the result you want to achieve

Comment: Hi Riccardo, nice to meet you! Sure I'll immediately do it! Sorry but my experience is really low and I'm trying to learn as much as I can about Python! Can you explain me how to attach an image to the comment in order to better explain myself???

Comment: Hi, just click on the image icon on the top bar of the insertion window and follow the instructions ;)

Comment: Ok... I've done it! I hope that, supporting my question with this image could help to better explain myself. I'd like to draw a smoother graphic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right Francesco, thanks for uploading the image. Now, let's have some fun with coding.

As first I suggest to use the numpy function to fit a polynomial curve of a certain degree to a set of value: np.polyfit(). Be aware of the degree you set as the results can widely change. For more information, please take a look at this documentation: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html

Then, in order to smooth your curve down, you need to increase the number of point to draw the function with np.linspace() and use this new set to apply the
function np.poly1d() (it calculates the y coordinates based on the fitting you did with polyfit).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

x = [0, 50, 100, 150, 200, 250]

y = [-1, 0.8, 1.9, 1.6, 0, -3]

z = np.polyfit(x, y, 2)

p = np.poly1d(z)

xp = np.linspace(-2, 255)
plt.plot(x, y, '.', xp, p(xp), '-')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Riccardo, with your help I've been able to solve my problems. I'm preparing another post because I've a little trouble more with a specifica kind of graphic and I'd like to share it with you!

Comment: If you think the question was correctly answered, can you tick it the reply as the solution? (grey ✓ mark on the left)